# smtp sends headers as content

Tags: google-app-engine, smtp

I'm using remote smtp server(from my host company) and send 
email from local computer.(google app development server)
But instead of getting nice emails
i get emails that contain headers as if it ware content of email
What can do to change it?

Comment: sample please. remove the header field's content if you want, but leave in all the header labels and the whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have a newline (\r\n or Carriage Return -Line Feed) in your subject. And, your mailing program doesn't strip newlines in the subject.

If you put a newline in the subject, and your app doesn't remove it, you just moved all following headers down to the body.

Answer (score 0):

Send the email according to the SMTP RFC: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321

Getting the headers in the content sounds like you sent them twice or did separate the headers from the content in a way your mail client does not understand.

Answer (score 0):

Check you don't have something wrapping what you send in another layer of email.

Perhaps look at the current (real/outer) headers to see if that gives any clues.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us your code, please? You don't say which App Engine runtime you're using; I'll assume Python. The App Engine mail API doesn't let you directly set message headers. There's a list of attributes you can set [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/emailmessagefields.html).